# How to validate successfull payment in asp.net website integrated with payment gateway

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a website integrated with payment gateway.Everything works fine,after succesfull payment it lands on my my success  page,but how do i validate that user has paid and not landing on my success page by url manipulation.
any help appreciated.

Comment: The payment gateway will send you some information back when it redirects back to your application... Depending on payment gateway, there must be some validation mechanism to verify if redirection is actually happening from the payment gateway and not from some other source... you need to check the payment gateway documentation about the validation mechanisms.

Comment: in the sample kit they provided.on success page they are displaying all the data they collected in their startup pages using request.form("txnid").and other details.any idea what request.form does

Comment: `request.form` is the collection of data submitted in the form.